# How to insert multi values to data-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I made a jquery filter function, that filtering the results by data-tags. like this:

```
<div class="resultblock" data-tag="ios">
        <img src="images/osx.jpg" class="itemimg">              
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="desc_text">
                lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
```

i just want to insert in the data-tag another tags to filter. like this:

```
data-tag="ios,android,windows"
```

How can i do that?

Comment: _"i just want to insert in the data-tag another tags to filter"_ Not sure what you mean? What are you filtering? What is purpose of including `",android,windows"`? What issue are you having?

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate a value to existing `data-*` attribute?

Comment: Where is your filter function? What do you want to do? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the question you are asking, but I think you could accomplish this via JS.

In your html add a `script` tag and then you just write some JS to edit or add html tags. Here is an example:

```
<script>
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
</script>
```

Now to sort the data-tag:
just add this code to your HTML file.

```
<div id="div1">
</div>

<script>
var tag ="ios,android,windows"; //initialize variable
var data = tag.split(","); //this makes an array of ios,andrid,windows
var i = 0;

while (i < 3){
  alert(i);
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
  para.appendChild(node);
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
  i++;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way doing this is to use classes. Adding classes and removing them is much easier than other attributes. The classes should not overlap with other classes used for CSS for example. Adding a prefix to them is even better. Like this:

```
$(".filter-ios").hide(); // hide all ios elements

$("something").addClass("filter-windows"); // add the class windows to an element

$(".filter-ios").addClass("filter-apple"): // add the apple filter class to the ios filter class elements

$("something").hasClass("filter-samsung"); // check if an element has the filter class samsung
// ...
```

The classes `.filter-*` should be used for filtering only, they must not have any CSS attached to them, if there is already classes like that, then just change the prefix `filter` to something else!

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a little object with two methods `.add` and `.remove`. It works like `classList` DOM method for adding and removing classes. If you add one value twice, it's added only once, also if you remove some not existing class, any error will occure. Hope you'll find it helpful.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myElem');

multiValues = {
 add: function(elem,val){
  if(elem.constructor.toString().search('HTML')===-1) return;
  if(typeof val !=='string') return;
  if(!elem.attributes['data-tag']) elem.setAttribute('data-tag');
  
  var attr = elem.attributes['data-tag'];
  var parsed = attr.value.split(',');
  var isExist = parsed.some(function(a){
   return a === val;
  });
  if(!isExist) parsed.push(val);
  elem.setAttribute('data-tag',parsed.join(','));
 },
 remove: function(elem,val){
  if(elem.constructor.toString().search('HTML')===-1) return;
  if(typeof val !=='string') return;
  if(!elem.attributes['data-tag']) return;

  var attr = elem.attributes['data-tag'];
  var parsed = attr.value.split(',');
  parsed.some(function(a,b){
   if(a===val){
    parsed.splice(b,1);
   }
  elem.setAttribute('data-tag',parsed.join(',')); 
  });
 }
};

multiValues.add(el,'window');
multiValues.add(el,'window');
multiValues.add(el,'window');
multiValues.add(el,'android');
multiValues.remove(el,'a');
multiValues.remove(el,'b');
multiValues.add(el,'something');

console.log(el.attributes['data-tag'].value);
```

```html
<div class="resultblock" data-tag="ios" id="myElem"></div>
```